# How to sort a list in Scala by two fields?

Tags: scala, sorting, functional-programming

how to sort a list in Scala by two fields, in this example I will sort by lastName and firstName?

```
case class Row(var firstName: String, var lastName: String, var city: String)

var rows = List(new Row("Oscar", "Wilde", "London"),
                new Row("Otto",  "Swift", "Berlin"),
                new Row("Carl",  "Swift", "Paris"),
                new Row("Hans",  "Swift", "Dublin"),
                new Row("Hugo",  "Swift", "Sligo"))

rows.sortBy(_.lastName)
```

I try things like this

```
rows.sortBy(_.lastName + _.firstName)
```

but it doesn't work. So I be curious for a good and easy solution.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

```
rows.sortBy(r => (r.lastName, r.firstName))
```

Comment: what if we want to reverse sort on lastName and then natural sort on firstName?

Comment: @SachinK: you have to create your own `Ordering` for `Row` class and use it with `sorted` method like this: `rows.sorted(customOrdering)`. You could also use custom `Ordering` for `Tuple2` like this: `rows.sortBy(r => (r.lastName, r.firstName))( Ordering.Tuple2(Ordering.String.reverse, Ordering.String) )`.

Comment: @SachinK: You could implement `customOrdering` as `Ordering[Row]` manually or using `Ordering.by` like this: `val customOrdering = `Ordering.by((r: Row) => (r.lastName, r.firstName))( Ordering.Tuple2(Ordering.String.reverse, Ordering.String) )`

Comment: Excellent. Or to sort in descending order `rows.sortBy(r => (-r.field1, -r.field2))`

Comment: @BrentFaust you can't use `-` with `String`. You should use `Ordering::reverse` this way: `rows.sortBy(r => (r.lastName, r.firstName))(implicitly[Ordering[(String, String)]].reverse)`.

Comment: @BrentFaust see [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027543/how-to-sort-a-list-in-scala-by-two-fields/10027682?noredirect=1#comment37520015_10027682)

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre you have not the same `Row` class as in the question.

Answer (score 15):

```
rows.sortBy (row => row.lastName + row.firstName)
```

If you want to sort by the merged names, as in your question, or

```
rows.sortBy (row => (row.lastName, row.firstName))
```

if you first want to sort by lastName, then firstName; relevant for longer names (Wild, Wilder, Wilderman).

If you write

```
rows.sortBy(_.lastName + _.firstName)
```

with 2 underlines, the method expects two parameters:

```
<console>:14: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
       rows.sortBy (_.lastName + _.firstName)
                               ^
```

Comment: The order of this will probably not be the same as sorting by firstname, then lastname.

Comment: Specifically, when last names are diffferent lengths

Comment: Well, you can add a delimiter, which is not part of regular names, like `rows.sortBy (row => row.lastName + " " + row.firstName)`.

Answer (score 9):

In general, if you use a stable sorting algorithm, you can just sort by one key, then the next.

```
rows.sortBy(_.firstName).sortBy(_.lastName)
```

The final result will be sorted by lastname, then where that is equal, by firstname.

Comment: Are you sure that scala `sortBy` use stable sort? Otherwise this answer is meaningless.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Sorting$.html quickSort is defined only for value types, so yes.

Comment: `rows` is an immutable list and `sortBy` returns a new value rather than mutating that upon which it works (even in mutable classes). So your second expression is just sorting the original unsorted list.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Fixed, and noted.

Comment: Scala, under the hood of sortBy method uses java.util.Arrays.sort, which for array of objects guarantees to be stable. So, yes, this solution is correct. (This was checked in Scala 2.10)

Comment: It's interesting to think about the performance of this vs. a single sortBy that creates a tuple.  With this approach you obviously don't have to create those tuples, but with the tuple approach you only have to compare first names where last names match.  But I suppose it doesn't matter -- if you're writing performance-critical code you shouldn't be using sortBy at all!

Comment: To run two consecutive sorts on the entire data set when only a part is needed to be checked is bad for performance even if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do more complex stuff by using sortWith:

```
def customFn1(v1: SomeClass, v2: SomeClass): Boolean = ???

def customFn2(v1: SomeClass, v2: SomeClass): Boolean = ???

list.sortWith((v1, v2) => customFn1(v1, v2)).sortWith((v1, v2) => customFn2(v1, v2))
```

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps this works only for a List of Tuples, but

```
scala> var zz = List((1, 0.1), (2, 0.5), (3, 0.6), (4, 0.3), (5, 0.1))
zz: List[(Int, Double)] = List((1,0.1), (2,0.5), (3,0.6), (4,0.3), (5,0.1))

scala> zz.sortBy( x => (-x._2, x._1))
res54: List[(Int, Double)] = List((3,0.6), (2,0.5), (4,0.3), (1,0.1), (5,0.1))
```

appears to work and be a simple way to express it.

Comment: But doesn't work for strings, which is what the OP is sorting.

Comment: This question already has several well received answers which are not limited to lists of tuples. So what's the reason of posting it?

Comment: @honk:  The prior solutions actually do not work (AFAICT) on a List of Tuples.  If I were not a Scala newbie, perhaps I would understand how to morph those prior solutions to work in that case, but today I don't.  I thought that my answer might help another Scala newbie do the same thing I was trying to do.

Comment: @user3508605: I appreciate your will to contribute. However, the idea of Stack Overflow is to have questions with specific problems (as it is the case here) and answers that address those specific problems (and only those). Your answer provides a solution for a different problem. Therefore this is the wrong place to post it. If you think that your answer is valuable, then ask a new question. Describe your corresponding problem in the new question and then post your answer there. Finally don't forget to remove your answer here. Thank you for your cooperation!

Comment: @honk:  Sure, I'll move my answer to a separate question.                        And, if I could impose on you to add a comment to the previous answer to this question (from Marcin), it appears to be just wrong.  (I don't have enough credibility points to be able to post on it.)  The example in that answer just sorts first by one key and then sorts again by a different key, effectively eliminating the results of the first sort.  At least on a List of Tuples it does.

Comment: @honk: My previous comment about the previous answer is wrong; please disregard.

Comment: @honk:  The title only refers to sorting a List, not specifically a List of Strings as the OP.  Is it typical that the title and the OP not be tightly aligned?  Is it proper etiquette to modify the title to be more tightly aligned with the OP, or request the OPer to do so?

Comment: @user3508605: It would always be great, if the title exactly specified what the question is about. However, often not all details of a question fit into the title. Therefore, the content of the question is what is relevant for the answers. Anyway, if you see the need to improve a post then you can edit it and propose your improvement. However, make sure that you improve the complete post, if necessary, and not only the title. Very small edits are often rejected. As for this question, I think the title is almost ok.