# How to sort a list in Scala by an unknown number of items?

Tags: scala, sorting, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have seen this question [How to sort a list in Scala by two fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027543/how-to-sort-a-list-in-scala-by-two-fields)

This is similar but not a duplicate.

I can easily sort a `List[DataPoint]` using the answer from the earlier question:

```
case class DataPoint(keys: List[String], value: Double)

listOfDataPoints.sortBy(point => (point.keys(0), point.keys(1)))
```

However I don't know the number of items in `keys`. What I do know is that every `DataPoint` in a given list will have the same number of keys, so there is never a case of sorting `List("a")` and `List("a", "b")`.

So how can I sort the list by an unknown number of keys?

Comment: In what order are List("a") and List("a", "b") sorted?

Comment: Added a clarification.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is

```
datapoints.sortby(_.keys)
```

This evidently doesn't work. When we take a look at the signature of sortby, it becomes evident why it doesn't work:

```
sortBy[B](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): List[A]
```

Your `B` is a `List[String]` and you don't have an instance of `Ordering[List[String]]`. So what do we do? We supply one!

What we need to do for that is implement the method

```
def compare(x: T, y: T): Int
```

We want to compare on the following:

- If the first key is different between two items, then use that key for sorting
- Otherwise, sort by the rest of the List
- If one of the lists is empty, the other one comes first<sup>[1]</sup>

Our T's here are Strings, but all we need for the T's is to be comparable for this, so we can be a little more general.

```
def listOrdering[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[List[T]] = new Ordering[List[T]] {
  def compare(x: List[T], y: List[T]): Int = {
    (x, y) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => 0 //both empty => equal
      case (Nil, _)   => -1 //one of the two empty => empty is the smallest
      case (_, Nil)   => 1 //one of the two empty => empty is the smallest
      case (xhead :: xtail, yhead :: ytail) => {
        val headdiff = ord.compare(xhead, yhead)
        if (headdiff == 0) compare(xtail, ytail) //recursively compare the tails if equivalent
        else (headdiff ) //otherwise, the difference in the heads
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

now we can supply the ordering to the sortby method explicitly:

```
datapoints.sortby(_.keys)(listOrdering)
```

or provide them in implicit scope

<sub>[1]: you indicated this never happens, so any choice is good enough</sub>

Comment: Brilliant that looks like the solution, I will give it a try.

Comment: As a comment, while my implementation is aimed at explaining to the maximum extent, @Shadowlands implementation is far more concise and probably more self-evident for many

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own `Ordering[List[String]]`. For example, you could define:

```
class ListOrdering[A](implicit aOrd: math.Ordering[A]) extends Ordering[List[A]] {    
  def compare(a1: List[A], a2: List[A]) = (a1, a2) match {
    case (Nil, _) => if (a2.isEmpty) 0 else -1
    case (_, Nil) => 1
    case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) => if (aOrd.compare(h1, h2) == 0) compare(t1, t2) else aOrd.compare(h1, h2)
  }    
}
```

Then making the following available somewhere in scope:

```
implicit val listOrd = new ListOrdering[String]
```

you can write:

```
dps.sortBy(_.keys)
```

and it should work.

Note that my definition of `ListOrdering` is generalised to be useable for any type `A` with an implicit `Ordering[A]` in scope, and can handle lists of variable length (even though you say that in your case your key lists are always the same length).

Comment: this implies that if (h1 != h2) compare(h1, h2) != 0 which doesn't need to be the case