# Build user-friendly API to sort by multiple criterias

Tags: scala, sorting

I'd like to know if this is possible to build an API that allows to sort by multiple criterias at the same time. I know it's possible to sort on tuples and I'm not looking for an alternative solution proposal, my question is also for improving my knowledge regarding the problem I'm currently facing.

Currently my code looks like:

```
object MultiSort {

  case class SortByCriteria[ItemType, SortType](
    sortBy: ItemType => SortType,
    ordering: Ordering[SortType]
  )

  def sort[ItemType](items: List[ItemType])(sortByList: List[SortByCriteria[ItemType, _]]) = {
    sortByList.foldRight(items) { case (sortByCriteria, acc) =>
      acc.sortBy(item => sortByCriteria.sortBy(item)(sortByCriteria.ordering)
    }
  }

}
```

[Because sortBy is stable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10027606/82609), I should be able to apply multiple `sortBy` in a raw and get by result sorted by multiple criterias. Unfortunatly I'm struggling to express what I want with the type system, because my list of criterias is heterogenous `List[SortByCriteria[ItemType, _]]`

So, I'd like to know how can I apply multiple `sortBy` in a row and keep the type system happy

Comment: What should the return type of `sort` be? and what is the type error you're getting now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a common one in scala. When you put all the SortByCriteria in a List, you lose the specific type because the list forces all the items to a common super type. The trick is to move the code that requires the type-specific knowledge to a compilation unit that still has that information:

```
case class SortByCriteria[ItemType, SortType](
  sortBy: ItemType => SortType,
  ordering: Ordering[SortType]
) {
  def sort (items: List[ItemType]): List[ItemType] = 
    // this is the line that needs to know the `SortType`
    // so we move it to the code that has that information
    items.sortBy(sortBy)(ordering)
}

// not tested
// not sure about this, but hopefully gets the point accross
def sort[ItemType](items: List[ItemType])(sortByList: List[SortByCriteria[ItemType, _]]) = {
  sortByList.foldRight(items) { case (sortByCriteria, acc) =>
    sortByCriteria.sort(acc)
  }
}
```

Comment: Obviously :) I should have found this myself