# How to implement sort logic ascending order on 4 columns

Tags: scala, sorting

I tried below logic for sorting a file but I need to implement sort on a file for four columns. Can anyone tell me the way for sorting a text file implementing sort on 4 columns.

```
indata.sortBy(x => (x.split("|")(1).toInt, -x.split("|")(4).toInt).map(p => println(p)))
```

Comment: there are answers already on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027543/how-to-sort-a-list-in-scala-by-two-fields/10027682

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to split the data into columns and sort by each column in turn:

```
val cols = indata.map(_.split(raw"\|").toList)

cols.sortBy(_(3)).sortBy(_(2)).sortBy(_(1)).sortBy(_(0))
```

Splitting the data before sorting allows you to verify that the data is valid and fix it if necessary, and is more efficient than splitting it during the sort.

You could write an ordering function for use with `sortWith` but this is more complex, and the simpler solution is usually better.

Comment: Thank you 
I am getting expected output but I want to write this to a file
as per my requirement to save to a file
can you help to write this to a file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the source data in a text file, you can pass a function with the split columns placed in a `tuple` in specific order to method `sortBy` (so that you only need to sort the list in a single traversal):

```
// /path/to/infile
2|101|23|2
1|103|23|3
2|102|22|1
3|101|21|2
1|103|23|1

import scala.io.Source

val indata = Source.fromFile("/path/to/infile").
  getLines.toList
// indata: List[String] = List(2|101|23|2, 1|103|23|3, 2|102|22|1, 3|101|21|2, 1|103|23|1)

val outdata = indata.
  map( _.split("\\|").map(_.toInt) ).
  sortBy(r => (r(0), -r(1), r(2), r(3))).  // Ordering: (asc, desc, asc, asc)
  map(_.mkString("|"))
// outdata: List[String] = List(1|103|23|1, 1|103|23|3, 2|102|22|1, 2|101|23|2, 3|101|21|2)
```

Note that the columns being sorted are numeric (assumption based on your sample code), hence the `negative r(1)` in the example results in descending order.

To write the sorted list back to a file, just use a `PrintWriter`:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.PrintWriter

val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("/path/to/outfile"))

outdata.foreach(line => writer.write(line + "\n"))
writer.close
```

[UPDATE]

In case there is a mix of Int/String columns and ascending/descending orderings, you would need to specify [Ordering[T].reverse](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html#reverse:scala.math.Ordering[T]) for the column to be sorted in descending ordering.  In addition, you would also need to break the columns down in accordance with the ascending/descending switches to perform `sortBy` multiple times.  For example:

```
// /path/to/infile
2|"a"|101|23
1|"c"|103|23
2|"b"|102|22
3|"a"|101|21
1|"c"|103|23

val dscStrOrder = scala.math.Ordering[String].reverse

val outdata = indata.
  map( _.split("\\|") ).
  sortBy(r => (r(2).toInt, r(3).toInt)).
  sortBy(r => r(1))(dscStrOrder).
  sortBy(r => r(0).toInt).        // Ordering: (asc, desc, asc, asc)
  map(_.mkString("|"))
// outdata: List[String] = List(1|"c"|103|23, 1|"c"|103|23, 2|"b"|102|22, 2|"a"|101|23, 3|"a"|101|21)
```

Comment: Thanks Its working but how we can implement few columns in ascending and few columns in descending

Comment: For numeric values (as your sample code has indicated), you can simply replace selected columns with their negative values for sorting.  Please see revised answer.

Comment: Hi Leo 
In my file have second column have characters and when I am using this logic I am getting below error

Error:(11, 52) too many arguments for method sortBy: (f: Array[String] => B)(implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[B])List[Array[String]]
    val outdata = indata.map(_.split("\\|")).sortBy(r => r(0), -r(1)).map(_.mkString("|"))
                                                   ^

once have a look and suggest

Comment: In that case, it would require breaking up the columns with separate sorting.  Please see my expanded answer.