# How to sort a list of custom objects by a specific field in Scala

Tags: list, scala, sorting

I'm working on a Scala project where I need to sort a list of custom objects based on a specific field. The objects have a field called `score`, which is an integer. I want to sort the list of objects in descending order based on this field.

Here's what I have so far:

```java
case class MyObject(id: String, score: Int)
val myObjects = List(MyObject("1", 5), MyObject("2", 3), MyObject("3", 8))

val sortedObjects = myObjects.sortWith((a, b) => a.score > b.score)
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient or idiomatic way to do this in Scala.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list in Scala by two fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027543/how-to-sort-a-list-in-scala-by-two-fields)

Answer (score 3):

```scala
myObjects.sortBy(x => -x.score)
// minus to get reverse natural order
```

Documentation: [https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sortBy[B](f:A=%3EB)(implicitord:Ordering[B]):C](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sortBy%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB)(implicitord:Ordering%5BB%5D):C)

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the implicit parameter for `sorted`/`sortBy`. For example with Scala 3:

```scala
given Ordering[MyObject] = Ordering.by(-_.score)
val sortedObjects = myObjects.sorted
```